Merge query in SQL Server suddenly going into suspended
I have a SQL Server MERGE query that has been working fine in production without any issues for last 3+ months but suddenly, it is getting stuck.
I also checked with infrastructure team to confirm no changes were made to the existing DB server.
After some research, I ran this query below to get more details and it seems the merge got suspended with wait_type CXPACKET or CXCONSUMER.
SELECT  
    wt.session_id, 
    ot.task_state, 
    wt.wait_type, 
    wt.wait_duration_ms, 
    wt.blocking_session_id, 
    wt.resource_description, 
    --es.[host_name], 
    es.[program_name] 
FROM
    sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks  wt  
INNER JOIN 
    sys.dm_os_tasks ot ON ot.task_address = wt.waiting_task_address 
INNER JOIN  
    sys.dm_exec_sessions es ON es.session_id = wt.session_id 
WHERE 
    es.is_user_process =  1
    AND es.session_id = 84
    AND wait_type != 'CXCONSUMER'




session_id
task_state
wait_type
wait_duration_ms
blocking_session_id
resource_description
program_name




84
SUSPENDED
CXPACKET
616
84
exchangeEvent id=Pipe223d33ce580 WaitType=e_waitPipeNewRow waiterType=Producer nodeId=20 tid=5 ownerActivity=receivedData waiterActivity=tryToSendData merging=false spilling=false waitingToClose=false
Python


84
SUSPENDED
CXPACKET
4129
84
exchangeEvent id=Pipe223d33ce280 WaitType=e_waitPipeNewRow waiterType=Producer nodeId=20 tid=4 ownerActivity=receivedData waiterActivity=tryToSendData merging=false spilling=false waitingToClose=false
Python


84
SUSPENDED
CXPACKET
839
84
exchangeEvent id=Pipe223d33ce280 WaitType=e_waitPipeNewRow waiterType=Producer nodeId=20 tid=1 ownerActivity=receivedData waiterActivity=tryToSendData merging=false spilling=false waitingToClose=false
Python


84
SUSPENDED
CXPACKET
11701531
84
exchangeEvent id=Port20e1b04a200 WaitType=e_waitPortOpen waiterType=Coordinator nodeId=5 tid=0 ownerActivity=notYetOpened waiterActivity=waitForAllOwnersToOpen
Python


84
SUSPENDED
CXPACKET
11701531
84
exchangeEvent id=Port20e1b04a200 WaitType=e_waitPortOpen waiterType=Coordinator nodeId=5 tid=0 ownerActivity=notYetOpened waiterActivity=waitForAllOwnersToOpen
Python


84
SUSPENDED
CXPACKET
11701531
84
exchangeEvent id=Port20e1b04a200 WaitType=e_waitPortOpen waiterType=Coordinator nodeId=5 tid=0 ownerActivity=notYetOpened waiterActivity=waitForAllOwnersToOpen
Python


84
SUSPENDED
CXPACKET
11701531
84
exchangeEvent id=Port20e1b04a200 WaitType=e_waitPortOpen waiterType=Coordinator nodeId=5 tid=0 ownerActivity=notYetOpened waiterActivity=waitForAllOwnersToOpen
Python


84
SUSPENDED
CXPACKET
11701531
84
exchangeEvent id=Port20e1b04a200 WaitType=e_waitPortOpen waiterType=Coordinator nodeId=5 tid=0 ownerActivity=notYetOpened waiterActivity=waitForAllOwnersToOpen
Python


84
SUSPENDED
CXPACKET
837
84
exchangeEvent id=Pipe223d33ce180 WaitType=e_waitPipeNewRow waiterType=Producer nodeId=20 tid=2 ownerActivity=receivedData waiterActivity=tryToSendData merging=false spilling=false waitingToClose=false
Python


84
SUSPENDED
CXPACKET
4128
84
exchangeEvent id=Pipe223d33ce280 WaitType=e_waitPipeNewRow waiterType=Producer nodeId=20 tid=3 ownerActivity=receivedData waiterActivity=tryToSendData merging=false spilling=false waitingToClose=false
Python



Note that I filtered out CXCONSUMER wait types because I read that CXPACKET should be the main focus. I read up on the resource description and still unclear what it all means.
I'm trying to troubleshoot why it would suddenly start getting suspended and stuck for hours when before, the merge would only take 5-10 mins.
Can anyone please advise me on what the issue is and what steps I should take to fix?
I didn't include my merge query as it's typical insert, updates and deletes but let me know if I should include in post. Thank you.
